# schunk_svh_driver how to use "channel_feedback"

Tags: ros, grasp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
can you suggest me how to use the topic channel_feedback to control the grasps of objects online?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207933/schunk_svh_driver-how-to-use-%22channel_feedback%22/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-26**:
check http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_svh_driver  section 5.4 visualization

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-27**:
Thank you for the answer, but when I try to have the visualization and I call:

```
roslaunch schunk_svh_driver    svh_controller.launch    standalone:=true gui:=true
```

a window is opened but there isn't the image of schunk hand and there is "Global Status: Error".

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-27**:
you dont read much, or?

RVIZ shows nothing like the screenshot when i load it

```
You need to configure it yourself to show the robot model and maybe the TF tree or use the provided config file at "etc/urdf.rviz"
```

http://wiki.ros.org/schunk_svh_driver

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-27**:
How I can use the provided config file at "etc/urdf.rviz"?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2015-04-27**:
http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials

**Comment by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on 2015-04-27**:
Sorry, but it's not clear to me..Must I write a launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I solved my problem. It is necessary to changes parameters in "displays" of rivz. In particular in my case the problem war the value assumed by "fixed frame": it is necessary to copy the right values of parameters by file at "etc/urdf.rviz"

---

Originally posted by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) with karma: 20 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0